# Timer functionally with increment option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-canvas

Am looking for timer functionality, which by clicking "+" symbol inside the clock, time should be incremented by 60 seconds during timer run time (only once), while increment, length of the red circle should decrease and then should run according to the count down.. please advice?

Here you can see code:
[JSBIN Link](http://jsbin.com/meqisobe/1/edit)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to include a js file for the support of

```
    .on('click',function(){});
```

I just added the new jquery file 1.9 to it and its running properly. Check this http://jsbin.com/meqisobe/9/edit

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but it seems not increment in timer countdown, and the timer stop at 60 sec instead of 0 sec, am looking for "by clicking "+" icon, timer should increase by 60 seconds (only once) and the red circle around it should run synchronously with the timer... please let me know if you cant able to understood my points...

Comment: Timer means the time already completed or the overall time for completion should Increase. and with http://jsbin.com/meqisobe/12/edit I see it stops at 0.

Comment: Overall time should increase by 60 seconds, it stops at 0 only if we not clicking the "+" symbol, But on clicking the "+" symbol - it stops at 60, and timer in not incremented by 60 seconds, actually it  should increment by 60 seconds and stops at 0 on clicking "+" symbol and please your post will be more helpful for us...

Comment: @SSS Could you help me understand what the questioner wants?

Comment: @markE The questioner wants to increase the countdown timer value. ie if the timer is set for 4 secs and if we press '+' then it would change to 5 secs. But also the circlular arc should adjust with it.

Comment: @user3483700 I guess that can be done. But your method of creating a arc is bit of an issue. You are creating arc bit by bit. And hence it wont be easy to calculate back and delete the arc. Instead find a way to create the circle from direct 0 itself hence if the timer is readjusted then you wont have to bother about deleting the arc.

Comment: @markE, thanks for your comments, but the requirement is that arc should delete 5 sec back then it should continue, it should not reset to "0" while clicking "+", please advice...

Comment: @user3483700 I guess your comment was directed at me, as I had commented that thing. I agree that your arc should deleted instead. But for that you need to do reverse calculations. I am not saying it should reset to zero but I am saying is try to find a method which will directly draw a arc from angle 0. Because using that you wont need to add arc but recreate the arc